# Plastic SCM external diff on Mac

Tags: plasticscm, araxis

I am attempting to set up Araxis diff as my external diff tool on Mac.

Command Line Reference:
http://www.araxis.com/merge_mac/command_line.html

I have set up a diff tool in the Diff Tool Configuration in the Preferences panel of Plastic with the following settings:

External Diff Tool ( selected )
Path: /usr/local/bin/compare -wait @sourcesfile @destinationfile
Use this tool for text files ( selected )

I have also attempted setting specific extensions and removing all other diff tools to no avail.

The internal diff tool shows up regardless of the settings.

Please advise what would be my next steps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the priority arrows to set your new diff and merge tool in the first position. If a diff or merge tool is on top with no file type restriction that is the one that is going to be used, make sure your new Araxis merge tool is on top.

In order to configure the diff tool with more details I do recommend you to use the following configuration:

```
"/usr/local/bin/compare"  /wait /2   /title1:"@sourcesymbolic" /title2:"@destinationsymbolic" @sourcefile @destinationfile
```

And for the merge tool you can use the following one:

```
"/usr/local/bin/compare" /wait /a3 /3 /title1:"@sourcesymbolic" /title2:"Workspace version" /title3:"@basesymbolic" @sourcefile @destinationfile @basefile @output
```

You will have this new tool available for the merge and file diff. The branch, changeset... will remain the built-in one.